# Project management and version control software

Tags: svn, git, project-management, software-distribution

We are about to embark on a biggish (academic) project which is divided into subprojects (with little if any code shared between them). None of the differences between git and svn make much difference to us, but we'd like to put each subproject in its own repository collected under a single project title. Which is the best way to approach managing the project?
Ideally, we'd like:

- bug-tracking
- a forum
- a wiki
- some kind of task-planner (like a Gantt chart)
- private as well as public repository branches

What solution would be best, in the opinion of stackoverflowers? I'd like to use github but it has a slightly steeper learning curve, and no forum. We could also use GForge on our own servers, but has a kludgy interface and it doesn't seem well-supported. Would Sourceforge be better? Or something I haven't thought of?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Doesn't seem that argumentative to me - there have been some very useful suggestions for me to look into.

Answer (score 5):

You might like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

- It may have many projects with subprojects. Each of them may have its own repository assigned.
- Bug tracking and project/tasks
  planning is very convenient with
  it.
- It has wiki integrated.
- It has  good integration with version control
  systems.
- I think newest versions have private projects.

Comment: Thanks. I notice no-one is suggesting I'm wrong about GForge...

Answer (score 1):

[unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) seems like a good fit,

Comment: I've used both this and Redmine; between them, Redmine is miles better.

Answer (score 1):

github is great. If you need it to be private, github is cheap, but you could probably send Tim or Scott an email or tweet saying it's for academic purposes and they would wave the fee. Never hurts to ask.

Comment: AFAIK gitorious also does free private repos. The UI isn't as nice as github though

Answer (score 0):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) has a [free for students edition](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html) that has everything you mentioned with [Mercurial (Hg)](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) version control integration & hosting ([intro to Hg if you need it](http://hginit.com/)) but can also integrate with SVN.  You could also use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to host your code (Mercurial hosting equivalent of GitHub).

Comment: What was the reason for the down vote?